# What's the best way to obtain all the combinations (Cartesian product) of lists?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have the following.

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
```

How do I obtain the following?

```
[1,2,3,'a','b']
[1,2,3,'c','d']
[1,2,3,'e','f']
[4,5,6,'a','b']
[4,5,6,'c','d']
[4,5,6,'e','f']
[7,8,9,'a','b']
[7,8,9,'c','d']
[7,8,9,'e','f']
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
from itertools import product
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]

print [x+y for (x,y) in product(a,b)]
```

Comment: That doesn't match the desired output: you need `product`, not `zip`.

Comment: Sorry then :) somehow my browser didn't reflect it.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [1]: from itertools import product

In [2]: a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

In [3]: b = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]

In [4]: map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], product(a, b))
Out[4]: 
[[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b'],
 [1, 2, 3, 'c', 'd'],
 [1, 2, 3, 'e', 'f'],
 [4, 5, 6, 'a', 'b'],
 [4, 5, 6, 'c', 'd'],
 [4, 5, 6, 'e', 'f'],
 [7, 8, 9, 'a', 'b'],
 [7, 8, 9, 'c', 'd'],
 [7, 8, 9, 'e', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> b = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
>>> [x+y for x in a for y in b]
[[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3, 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 'e', 'f'], [4, 5, 6, 'a', 'b'], [4, 5, 6, 'c', 'd'], [4, 5, 6, 'e', 'f'], [7, 8, 9, 'a', 'b'], [7, 8, 9, 'c', 'd'], [7, 8, 9, 'e', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
c = []
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        print x + y
        c.append(x + y)
```

Answer (score 1):

just for fun, because answer from Maria is much better:

```
from itertools import product
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
print [sum(x, []) for x in product(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to see if you could condense the `product` expression, I came up with this:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> map(lambda x: sum(x, []), product(a, b))
[[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3, 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 'e', 'f'], [4, 5, 6, 'a', 'b'], [4, 5, 6, 'c', 'd'], [4, 5, 6, 'e', 'f'], [7, 8, 9, 'a', 'b'], [7, 8, 9, 'c', 'd'], [7, 8, 9, 'e', 'f']]
```